# How to prevent android system fonts setting from changing the fonts in react-native apps?

Tags: android, react-native, fonts

So we have this weird bug when the users change the font type to Bold. it ruin the app's layout, and the icons fail to load, instead of icons it show [x] symbol or some Chinese characters (I think this behavior depends on the user's phone).

[image]

Comment: The used by app icons don't support BOLD font weight. Is practical to disable the app accessibility setting?

Comment: @FistonEmmanuel yeah if it's possible, since not only the icons but it broke the layouts too, eg; the text not fully shown

Comment: @QrQr hm, if user change system's font size, you want app's font size not scale by system, right?

Comment: @VuPhung if possible, and the apps won't be affected by the Bold text's setting

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Other way, you can use custom componets to control this issue. for example,

```
import React from 'react';
import {StyleSheet, Text, TextStyle} from 'react-native';

type Props = {
  children: any;
  color: string;
  fontSize: number;
  style?: TextStyle;
};

export default function TextNormal({
  children,
  color,
  style,
  fontSize,
}: Props) {
  return (
    <Text style={[styles.text, {color, fontSize}, style]}>{children}</Text>
  );
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  text: {
    fontWeight: 'normal',
  },
});
```

Comment: thanks this solution work for missing icon too, since the icons is text adjusting fontWeight to normal will fix that problem too

Answer (score 1):

To disable scale app's font size by system's font size, just disable `allowFontScaling` props in `Text` tag, example:

```
<Text allowFontScaling={false}>Demo</Text>
```

For the Bold text's setting, i don't have any idea for this.

Comment: yeah we have implemented that solution before

Answer (score -1):

You can add this code to `index.js`

```
    AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => App);

    if (Text.defaultProps == null) {
        Text.defaultProps = {};
        Text.defaultProps.allowFontScaling = false;
    }
```

It will disable all the text in app to scaling.

Comment: we have implemented this solution before, but we still have the bold font issue